# Workload Scheduler job won't enable

Tags: ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

I'm trying to create a Workload Scheduler job that executes a curl command.

In `Steps` I've selected `Start a program` for the step and `RP_CLOUD` as the `Agent`(it's the only option). I pasted my curl command into `Program`.

Now when I try to enable the job I get a popup saying `<b>AWSUI4177E</b><br />AWSUI4177E Unable to update the Process.<br /><i>AWSUI4299E An internal error has occurred: AWSPRE001E The user "paul.carron@anaeko.com.5c81ed484ccf4c54aa9e348e" cannot create a job of type "executable" on the "RP_CLOUD" workstation. Download and install a Workload Automation Agent on a different machine.</i>`.

The curl statement works when executd in my Terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some security constrains on running jobs on the agents provided by the infrastructure.
I see two options:

1. Use the restful job type (since you are invoking a curl command)
2. Install an agent

Comment: Cheers @Umberto Castelli. I went for the restful job. Seems to be working.